# Extension functions does not work for dynamic objects

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have a Extension Function named `ParseLong` for string.

```
public static long ParseLong(this string x, long Default = 0) 
{ 
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) 
     long.TryParse(x, out Default);
 return Default; 
}
```

And works fine:

```
long x = "9".ParseLong();
```

However for dynamic objects like:

```
dynamic x = GetValues();
x.StartValue.ToString().ParseLong();
```

generates the error:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ParseLong'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Correct, extension functions do not work for `dynamic` objects. That is because the dynamic object, when being told to execute `ParseLong`, has **no clue** what `using` directives were in your C# code, so cannot guess what you want to do.

Extension methods are 100% a compiler feature (only); `dynamic` is primarily a runtime feature (although the compiler has to help it in places).

You could just cast, though, if you know the type:

```
long x = ((string)x.StartValue).ParseLong();
```

(which swaps back from `dynamic` to regular C#, so extension methods work)